# convert a URL to an image using sql request/postgresdatabase

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, type-conversion

I want display a URL in form of image using an SQL clause.

Actually my image is displayed as a link:

```
https://xxx.fr/DB/2010/05/databasename/filename_64.png
```

and I want to display it as an image not a link.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What SQL client are you using that is capable of displaying images at all?

Comment: it's the client side of an elasticsearch catalog. in the backoffice, I configure the field which I define it as an SQL clause and in the front end, the user can visuzalize this field. Actually he's visualizing it as a link, but I prefer to display it as image.

Comment: I also have the possibility to upload a json file instead of define the field using an SQL clause. I don't know if It helps ..! thank you !